# Configure Zebra printers properties using code

Tags: zebra-printers

I'm using Zebra ZD220. I have managed to configure some of the printer's setting using the SGD functions. But when I am printing, the settings are returning to window's default. Is there any "Save" or "Set Default" function that I need to use in order to save my changes?

Comment: Please show, what you print. A file containing ZPL commands?

Comment: No, I am trying to print an excel file. But it doesn't matter, even printing a blank page sets the printer's properties back to default.

Comment: Can you print to a text file and show the result?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. The printing operation resets the settings that I need to configure. Besides I don't print anything.

Comment: There are ZPL commands for printer settings. Maybe they are sent with your content. I guess your are not using a Generic/Text only printer driver?

Comment: As far as I know there are no ZPL commands that are being sent with my SGD commands.  I'm using the Windows driver for ZDesigner